# Invalid Signature when trying POST comment in CKEDITOR using FastAPi (Python)

Tags: python, ckeditor, fastapi

**This is my service to add comment:**

```
def add_comment_by_document_id(comment: request_schema.CreateComment):
timestamp = int(time()) * 1000
comment_path = "comments" if comment.document_id is None else f"comments?document_id={comment.document_id}"
ckeditor_url = get_ckeditor_url(comment_path).geturl()
parsed_url = urlparse(ckeditor_url)

path = parsed_url.path
post_data = {
    "id": comment.id,
    "document_id": comment.document_id,
    "thread_id": comment.thread_id,
    "content": comment.content,
    "user": {
        "id": comment.user.id
    },
    "thread": {
        "id": comment.thread.id
    }
}
signature = generateSignature("POST", path, timestamp, post_data)
headers = {
    "X-CS-Signature": signature,    
    "X-CS-Timestamp": str(timestamp)
}
response = requests.post(ckeditor_url, headers=headers, json=post_data)
return response.json()
```

**This is my get_ckeditor_url function:**

```
def get_ckeditor_url(url_param: str):
url_param = CKEDITOR_API_URL + url_param
url = urlparse(url_param)
return url
```

**This is my generate signature function:**

```
def generateSignature(method, url_param, timestamp, body):
url = get_ckeditor_url(url_param)
path = url.path

if url.query:
    path += "?" + url.query

methodUpperCase = method.upper()
dataString = methodUpperCase + path + str(timestamp)

if body:
    dataString += json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':'))

return hmacDigest(dataString, CKEDITOR_API_SECRET)
```

**That's my response**

```
{
  "message": "Invalid signature.",
  "trace_id": "5b9a1eef-5cbb-4b59-bb6a-3ce5fbcd2a76",
  "status_code": 401,
  "data": {
    "signature": "<MyToken>"
  },
  "level": "trace"
}
```

**Note**: *but when trying to get all comments it work's*
-I try using CKEditor generate signature function it's like COPY + PASTE but still the same and it's generate different signature

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post all code, input, output, and errors as plain text.

Comment: I already change it, thank you for your advice